# How to change datetime value via functions in django?

Tags: django, datetime

I have code within a context processor that displays the date in a navbar via the {{date}} tag using the function I created:

```
import datetime

def date(request):
nav_date = datetime.date.today()
return {
    "date" : nav_date
}
```

However, I would like to create a function to change the date so that whenever a button is clicked in the html code, the function would push the date from the nav_date variable 1 day forward.

```
 def next_day(request):
 # add 1 to nav_date and return value
```

Comment: after clicking the button, should the value of the nav_bar will also increase or will it remain same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some kind of common storage for sync button click with context processor's `date`. I am using session for this example. So you can try like this:

```
# context processor

def date(request):
    nav_date = request.session.get('nav_date')
    if nav_time:
       nav_time=datetime.datetime.strptime(nav_time, '%d-%m-%Y')
    else:
       nav_time = datetime.date.today()
    return {
        "date" : nav_date
    }
```

now need to write a view for updating the date and storing it in session:

```
def update_date(request):
   nav_date = request.session.get('nav_date')
   if nav_time:
       nav_time=datetime.datetime.strptime(nav_time, '%d-%m-%Y')
   else:
       nav_time = datetime.date.today()
   updated_nav_date = nav_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
   request.session['nav_date'] = updated_nav_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
   return HttpResponse("Date Updated")
```

define urls:

```
path('upate-date/' update_date, name="update_date")
```

Use it in the form:

```
<form action='{% url "update_date" %}' method='GET'>
    <button type='submit'> Update Date</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I got the error "Object of type 'date' is not JSON serializable"

Comment: whenever I try to pass the date through a request i get that error. I think it has to do something with me needing to convert it to a string first...but idk how to?

error:
updated_nav_date = nav_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
TypeError: must be str, not datetime.timedelta

Comment: @RazorEdgeE. yes, sorry I missed that earlier. I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: it did help immensely. Just make sure to correct the nav_time to nav_date cause nav_time variable doesn't exist. thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `timedelta` function to add/subtract days.

```
nav_date = nav_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: How do I get nav_date value from the date function into a new function?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want.  Do you want your `date()` function to return today's date, and then later in some other code you would add a day to it, or do you want `date()` itself to return the future date?

Comment: I would like the date() to only return today's date. I would like for another function to return the value of the date() function + 1 (the day after the date function)

so it would take the date value from date(), add 1 to it and return the new value under the same {{date}} tag, hence updating the value of date where the {{date}} tag is used in the template

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need is a counter on the frontend or have a url with the number of days to increment.

i.e GET `/?number_of_days=1`

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone


def date(request):
    nav_date = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=request.GET.get('number_of_days', 0))
    return {
        "current_date" : nav_date.date()
    }
```

There's also a templatetag which can be used to format dates.
     https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#now

```
 It is {% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
```

Which should be It is 2nd December 2018 18:11